# Unexpected error while parsing from string to map

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a flutter newbie.

I have a list named readBooks

which looks like this:

```
[ 
  {_id: 1, 
   name: Factfulness, 
   author: Hans Rosling, 
   total: 352, 
   done: 0, 
   thumb: http://books.google.com..., 
   maf: 1, 
   start: {
     year: 2022, 
     month: 4, 
     day: 30
   }, 
   end: {
     year: 2022, 
     month: 4, 
     day: 30
    }
   }


  {_id: 2, 
   name: Somebook, 
   author: Some author, 
   total: 1000, 
   done: 0, 
   thumb: http://books.google.com..., 
   maf: 1, 
   start: {
     year: 2022, 
     month: 4, 
     day: 30
   }, 
   end: {
     year: 2022, 
     month: 4, 
     day: 30
    }
   }

  ]
```

I am using a ListView.builder to extract the data.

I am provided with an index from the listview.builder

```
//here index - > 0
```

here

```
readBooks[index]
```

should give me the first iteration of the list.

What do I want?

to get the individual values of the "start" object, but the catch is that the start object is stored as a string.

What I tried?

```
Map myMap = {};
myMap = jsonEncode(jsonDecode(readBooks[index]['start']));
```

What I got?

*The following FormatException was thrown building:
Unexpected character (at character 2)
{year: 2022, month: 4, day: 30}
^*

Comment: Is readBooks a valid json string?

Comment: Hey! thanks for responding. I already mentioned everything. readBooks is a List of json objects. And that json object contains an another json object which is "start" and start looks like: {
     year: 2022, 
     month: 4, 
     day: 30
   }

Comment: The dataset posted above is not a valid json.

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to encode my map to JSON before storing my data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to encode/decode your response multiple times. jsonDecode does that for you automatically.

When you will `jsonDecode(readBooks)`, you will be receiving List of Map.
So if

```
final decodedResponse = jsonDecode(readBooks)
for (final book in decodedResponse) {
   final start = book['start'];   //Start will be map
   final year = start['year'];    //int
   final month = start['month'];  //int
   final day = start['day']; //int
   //Do your task here.
}
```